# KineticJS resize text to fit inside rectangle with some padding

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

Here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/6VRxE/11/

I have a fixed size text box, which I would like to dynamically change the text, text size, and padding so that the text would fit inside a rectangle and be vertically aligned.

```
 var messageText = new Kinetic.Text({
      x: .25*stage.getWidth(),
      y: .25*stage.getHeight(), 
      width: .5*stage.getWidth(),
      height: .5*stage.getHeight(),
      fontSize: 10,
      fontFamily: 'Lucida Grande',
      text: 'Hello, click to continue',
      align: 'center',
      textFill: '#006400',
      stroke: 'gray',
      draggable: true,
      fill: 'white',
 });
```

I'd like to change the text with an event or function like so:

```
 messageText.on('click',function(){
      messageText.setText('hi');
      messageText.setFontSize(messageText.getHeight()/2);
      messageText.setPadding(messageText.getHeight()/5); //this was one possibility to do some alignment but doesn't work great
      stage.draw();
  });
```

Does anyone have a good solution to calculate text size dependent on length?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6VRxE/12/  this got me a little closer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6VRxE/25/ not quite there yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the below `padText` function accomplishes what you were looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Text Container Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/5.0.6/kinetic.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer,
                text = new Kinetic.Text({
                    text: 'Fit Me',
                    fill: 'black',
                    align: 'center'
                }),
                rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
                    width: 400,
                    height: 200,
                    stroke: 'red'
                }),
                stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                    width: rect.width(),
                    height: rect.height(),
                    container: 'container'
                });

            layer.add( text );
            layer.add( rect );

            stage.add( layer );

            padText( text, rect, 10 );

            layer.draw();

            function padText( text, container, amount ){
                while (( text.width() * 1.001 ) < container.width() - ( amount * 2 ))
                    text.fontSize( text.fontSize() * 1.001 );

                text.y(( container.height() - text.height() ) / 2 );

                text.width( container.width() );
                text.height( container.height() );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrsHx)